# How do you use ～たりする with ～たい to say things that you want to do?

Tags: grammar

I recently learned how to use ～たい to say things that I want to do; for example:

> えいが　を　みたい　です。
>
> I want to see a movie.

And I learned how to use ～たりする to say examples of things that I did, do, or will do:

> きのう、にほんご　を　べんきょう　したり、本　を　よんだり　しました。
>
> Yesterday, I did things like study Japanese, read a book, etc.

I am wondering how I would use these two constructions in order to say something like "I want to do things like watch a movie, study Japanese, read a book, etc." Is it possible to combine ～たい and ～たりする to make such a sentence, and if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really trust myself with my Japanese grammar skills so you might want to get a second opinion on this, but this is how I would translate "I want to do things like watch a movie, study Japanese, read a book, etc." into Japanese:

私は映画を見たり、日本語を勉強したり、本を読んだり**したい**です。

So starting with the usual X～たり、Y～たりします pattern the only thing that needs to change if you want to say "I want to do X, Y, etc." is the します at the end which becomes したい（です）.

I hope I make sense, I'm not very good at explaining stuff.

Comment: Oh, that actually makes a lot of sense! Thank you for the answer. I'm glad it turned out to be a lot simpler than I thought it would be. :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)